# Random draw with same ammount of digits Ruby

Tags: ruby

Im trying to do a random draw. This is my code:

```
puts (1..5).map{rand(00000..99999)}
```

I would like to know if there is some way to make the random draw be with as many digits as the others, say:
2222 would become 02222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a formatting issue. Numbers don't have leading digits. When you need leading digits, in you have to use strings at the point you display them.

This generates the string form you need directly, in case that is useful. `sprintf` is ideal for controlling display of numbers in this way:

```
puts (1..5).map{ sprintf('%05d', rand(00000..99999) ) }
```

Answer (score 3):

[*@Neil Slater*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21478265/2767755) is right. Here is another variant.

The same can be done using [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25)

```
puts (1..5).map{ '%05d' % rand(00000..99999) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String#rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-rjust)

```
puts (1..5).map{ rand(00000..99999).to_s.rjust(5,'0') }
```